# Does &*x operation create a copy?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I had some problems converting a `std::list<MyType>::iterator` to `MyType*`. I have an array of `MyType` and as I loop through it, I call some `void doSomething(const MyType* thing)`. Eventually I do this:

```
std::list<MyType> types = ... something here ...;
for( std::list<MyType>::const_iterator it = types.begin(), end = types.end(); it != end; ++it ) {
    doSomething(&*it);
}
```

My question is, whether I do or do not create a memory copy of the `MyType` by this operation:

```
&*it
```

Trying to simply pass the iterator as if it was pointer, or to cast the iterator to pointer raised compiler errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the sequence of `*` and `&` does not create a copy:

- `*` applied to an iterator produces a *reference*
- `&` applied to a reference produces the address of the original

Neither of these two steps requires copying of `MyType`'s *data*.

**Note:** When the presence of an overloaded operator `&` is a possibility, it is safer to use [`std::address_of(*it)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) expression.

Comment: It scares me that `&` can be overridden. But at the same time I am happy that C++ is not afraid of anything.

Answer (score 2):

One of the requirements for an iterator is that it be derefernceable -- i.e. `*it` be supported. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator. Whether `*it` returns a reference or a copy is not specified.

In theory, an implementation could return a copy when using `*it`.

In practice, most implementations return a reference when using `*it`. Hence, you most likely won't be seeing a copy being made when using `&*it`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the iterator is valid it is doing what your want.  And no, it does not create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your code is written, you are creating a copy of the pointer, but the memory being pointed to by the pointer should not be copied.

Broken down, you take the iterator object (`it`), you look at the `MyType` object referenced by the iterator (`*it`), and then get the address of this object (`&*it`). The pointer is then copied into the function and used as you desire.